# Allow domain account to modify ACL of particular service

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012

I have a windows domain account that I would like to be able to modify the ACL of a particular service. Currently this account is being used to run an installer, and the installer wants to do the ACL modifications but it is failing. The account is a local admin on the box, but apparently due to some group policy it is experiencing an audit failure as it tries to modify the ACL of a service.

How can I grant this permission to this account? I would prefer to not have to modify group policy if I can just explicitly configure the service.

I appreciate any pointers but especially complete answers since some of these concepts are quite new to me.

New information:

I was able to accomplish this goal but probably with too broad of a stroke ... in particular I modified the security descriptor for the service, using "sc sdshow" and "sc sdset", and gave the account every permission I could think of in the SDDL string ... in particular these: CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO

Does anyone know which of those actually corresponds to the "modify ACL" permission I was looking for?

Also does anyone know what group policy I have in place that was creating this problem to begin with (since in the absence of group policies the problem goes away)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is a group policy interfering with these permissions, I would recommend fixing the group policy.

You can do this by editing the offending group policy, drilling down to Computer Configuration > Windows Settings > Security Settings > System Services > Pick the service you want from the list and go to Properties. Edit Security... and add the "Change permissions" to the security principal you want in the Advanced Tab.

If you can't do that for some reason, you can keep using the `sc sdset` method you're using now... modify permissions is "WD" in SDDL. Beware that this probably won't stick though, if there is a GPO overriding it.

Comment: Thanks for the tips ... I'm curious about why my local administrator account didn't have this right. I'm thinking we might have modified a default policy. If I find that problem, it might be a better solution as opposed to fixing the issue for this on a service-by-service basis. The reason I think the default policy would work is because this error popped up in the sharepoint 2013 installer, and isn't documented anywhere, which makes me think a "Default environment" doesn't have this problem. Thanks for any more tips you can share... I'm just filling in as domain admin for a short time here

Comment: It was our windows update policy that had specifically locked down permissions on this service, which i guess is required by windows update and hence must be tightly controlled if we are to keep local admins from shutting down windows update